# Expression expected in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, vue.js

When I try to define callback function using

```
() => { }
```

instead of

```
function () {}
```

I get this error from PhpStorm

[image: Error]

How to fix this?

Comment: Which version of PhpStorm are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the menu:

PhpStorm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript

You'll see a box that says: JavaScript Language Version.

You should be able to change the option to ECMAScript 6 and apply.

Also:

PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor > File Types Find ECMAScript 6 in the list and add *.vue to the registered patterns list. You could add it to the Javascript file type to for good measure.

Comment: Yup I changed that option earlier but that didnt worked on .vue file (only .js), so I added script type in .vue "<script type="text/ecmascript-6">" and now it works:)

Comment: Ah PhpStorm for all it's brilliance certainly has a confusing settings window. To solve for that you need:

PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor > File Types

Find ECMAScript 6 in the list and add *.vue to the registered patterns list.

You could add it to the Javascript file type to for good measure.

Comment: I've been using `type="text/babel"` in case that works any differently for you